# Syntax Error in Mysql Delete Trigger with conditions

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, delimiter, delete-operator

I have written a small trigger function in MySQL . This is the trigger query i have written and give syntax error in code.

Error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'cp WHERE `cp`.`customer_plan_id`= first_id;

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_plan_on_delete_customer 
    AFTER DELETE ON customers
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE active_plan INT;
    DECLARE first_id INT;

    SET active_plan = (SELECT is_active
    FROM customer_plans 
    WHERE customer_id=OLD.customer_id AND first_plan_id=1);

    if(active_plan = 0)THEN

        SET first_id = (SELECT customer_plan_id
        FROM customer_plans 
        WHERE customer_id=OLD.customer_id AND first_plan_id=1);

        DELETE customer_plans cp WHERE `cp`.`customer_plan_id`= first_id;
   END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It should be `DELETE FROM customer_plans`

Comment: not working it gives same error @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: Can you provide a SQL fiddle, or edit your question to give table structures (just the relevant fields in the trigger)

Comment: Also, try to get rid of ` in the delete query?

Comment: it's still give the same error

Comment: please give Create table statements for customer_plans and customer table. Also what is your Mysql version ?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: Change to `DELETE FROM customer_plans WHERE customer_plan_id = first_id;`

Comment: It's working Thank you @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: Happy to help :) Kindly upvote and accept my answer :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270015/2469308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of `DELETE` query, from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) is:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Change your `DELETE` lines in the trigger to:

```
DELETE FROM customer_plans WHERE customer_plan_id = first_id;
```

**Sidenote:** Based on my personal experience, it is a good habit to [DECLARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) default values for the variables. eg:

```
DECLARE active_plan INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE first_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
```